# What is the process to buy bitcoin from our own portal with APIs?

Tags: bitcoin

We would like to have a service which allows the users to buy bitcoin from our own portal with APIs. Can anyone suggest what is the process to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Yep, Bitcoins can be bought through APIs. There are many third part APIs though which you can facilitate this feature on your portal  :

- Bitstamp
- Kraken
- ANXBTC
- BTC-e

Then, There a complete merchant solution provider :

- BitPay

**Ref :** https://blockchain.info/api/3rd_party_apis